# Outlook Needs to Be Open When Getting NewMail Events Via Exchange Web Services (C#)

Tags: c#, outlook, exchangewebservices

Title pretty much says it all. I tried searching for this topic, and couldn't find anything. I looked at [impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204095%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx) for Exchange Server 2010, but I don't know if impersonation isn't enabled on the server (or if that is even the issue) - and I'd like to be a bit more confident before I bug a sys admin. Is there anything else it could be?

I followed the MSDN tutorial for setting up a subscription and connection, using impersonation, and I still have to have Outlook open - otherwise, I never get *any event* including NewMail events, which are what I'm looking for.

Does anybody have any ideas?